# OAuth and authorization

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

I built a RESTful service with authentication mechanism. The authentication works with OAuth protocol (with the library from oauth.net).

My service is for school management. What I have now is only teachers panel. Now I want to add also students panel, wich its almost the same, but I dont want that students be able to edit things, so authorization is required in this case.

When the teacher wants to login, he sends post request to 'authentcation.php' and if the fields are valid, he get back the authentication token from the OAuth. The students login in 'authentication_students.php'

How can I check if the token have privilege to edit things or not with authorization in OAuth?

Comment: OAuth is for delegated authorization and authentication but not really for "pure authorization". That's what XACML is for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token validation is intentionally uncovered by the OAuth 2.0 specification, so the exact implementation is up to you. The server may either provide a custom endpoint where token validity can be checked by protected resources or issue tokens in a format that the client can directly interpret without consulting the server (see e.g. JWS: json web tokens with signatures).

If you're using a library, you can check which approach it supports.

Issuing the token you should request different scopes (analog to user roles) for teachers and students so you can permit or deny access to protected resources based on scopes of the token granted to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The token would need to include a claim with something like "canEdit" = true/false. In your case the authentication is done from two different pages, so it should not be a big problem to populate this claim?

Let me know if I'm totally off here? Am I missing something?

Comment: But how can I check this? How from the token I can get the canEdit value?